# Ember.js RC1 - register and inject

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to inject a Logger object into all Ember controllers, views, and models.

I tried the example here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/02/15/ember-1-0-rc/ in the "REGISTER AND INJECT" section and it doesn't seem to work.

```
var App = window.App = Em.Application.create({
    ...
    Logger: Em.Object.extend(),
    ...
});

App.register('logger:main', Em.Object.extend());
App.inject('model', 'logger', 'logger:main');
App.inject('view', 'logger', 'logger:main');
App.inject('controller', 'logger', 'logger:main');
```

In my view, when I try to get the logger, it is undefined:

```
this.get('logger');
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/98/edit)

I'm not sure why the view doesn't have a `logger` injected into it, but a workaround is to get `logger` from the view's controller:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Logger = Ember.Object.extend({
  log: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});

App.register('logger:main', App.Logger);
App.inject('model', 'logger', 'logger:main');
App.inject('view', 'logger', 'logger:main');
App.inject('controller', 'logger', 'logger:main');

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.get("controller.logger").log("log through controller");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the snippet! I'm having issues when the View is created by a handlebars template. [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/93/edit)

Comment: @sandeepmistry I updated the answer and jsbin example with a workaround for the view not receiving the injected `logger`.  I'm not sure why the view doesn't get `logger` injected...

Comment: Thanks @c4p, this works for now, I'll open a issue with ember.js

Comment: TYVM, I've been looking for a solution all day long.. and it's as simple as that.. great! :)